# Is the interval $[0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ compact in the topology generated by half open intervals $[a,b)$?

Tags: general-topology

> Is the interval $[0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ compact in the topology generated by half open intervals $[a,b)$?

I think not, but I cannot find a cover that wouldn't have a finite sub-cover. If I let $A_n=[0, 2+ \frac{1}{n})$, then I would have that $[0,2] \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n$, but I don't know how to check that if this cover has a finite sub-cover?

Comment: $[0,2]\subset A_1=[0,3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[0, 1), [1, 1.9), [1.9, 1.99), [1.99, 1.999), \cdots$.

Then add $[2, 3)$ to cover $2$.